# Program to find day on 1st jan of years 01 to 99; switch statement not working

Tags: c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>

     int main(void)
      {
      int year,dayextra,q,day;
      printf("enter the year");
      scanf("%d",&year);
      year=year-1;
      q=year/4;
      dayextra=year+q;
      day=dayextra%7;
      switch(day)
      {
       case '3':printf("\nmonday");
           break;
       case '4':printf("\ntuesday");
           break;
       case '5':printf("\nwed");
           break;
       case '6':printf("\nthu");
           break;
       case '7':printf("\nfri");
        break;
       case '1':printf("\nsat");
           break;
       case '2':printf("\nsun");
           break;  
      }
              getch();
       }
```

Comment: "is not working" isn't a diagnosis.

Answer (score 4):

`case '3'` is testing if `day` is equal to the ASCII value for the `3` character, which would be 63.  `day` cannot possibly have the value 63.  Try using `case 3` instead.  The same goes for all of your other cases.

My own testing has suggested that `case 0` should be Sunday, `case 1` Monday, and so on, up to `case 6` being Saturday.

Comment: upon changing '1' to 1 and '2' to 2...... now it tells illegal character... plz see

Answer (score 0):

One case in the switch statement is wrong. You are calculating day by using the following code

```
day=dayextra%7
```

But if you mod a number by 7, the output should be less than 7. So, your cases should be 0,1,2....6

That implies that your following case is wrong

```
case '7':printf("\nfri");
```

Re-arrange the code using following cases

```
switch(day)
  {
   case '0':printf("\nsun");
       break; 
   case '1':printf("\nmonday");
       break;
   case '2':printf("\ntuesday");
       break;
   case '3':printf("\nwed");
       break;
   case '4':printf("\nthu");
       break;
   case '5':printf("\nfri");
    break;
   case '6':printf("\nsat");
       break; 
  }
```

Hope this will work for you.